# Read a MS Word (doc) file page by page

Tags: microsoft-word-2003

Is there any way to make wvWare (or possible some other command line tool, or Python library) to read a doc file page by page? I can't seem to find anything in wvWare's manual, neither in Abiword, Antiword or catdoc.

Comment: what is Wvware and Wmware?

Comment: @Prasanna Sorry, should be wvWare. wv is [a library](http://wvware.sourceforge.net/) to view old Microsoft Word (`doc`) files. It is used by e.g. OpenOffice, LibreOffice and Abiword, so it's kind of the default library, I guess.

Comment: I know that Adobe reader has the ability to read pages out loud. May be you can convert your doc files to PDF and read page by page (even word by word)

Comment: @Prasanna Yep, converting to another format is an option, but I'm converting 100 000's of files, so I was hoping to avoid that if possible, to make the script a bit faster.

Comment: An insanely ugly way to do it would be to look for ^L in the original document and figure out where in the text they occur (non docx Word documents are mostly plain text).

Comment: @barrycarter Can you elaborate a bit? What is `^L`? A linefeed? (Yes, I'm trying to avoid reading [the docs](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/4/8/24862317-78F0-4C4B-B355-C7B2C1D997DB/[MS-DOC].pdf). In my defence, they are 627 pages)

Comment: ^L is control-L, character code 12 and sometimes called a "form feed" (the "linefeed character" is ^J, two characters earlier). If you look at a raw Word document in emacs (or any editor that shows control codes), you'll see one of these at the end of each page.

Comment: @barrycarter Thanks, if you add that info as an answer, I'll accept and upvote!

Comment: Done, although I feel bad about this, because I'm terrible about upvoting answers to my own questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An insanely ugly way to do it would be to look for ^L in the original document and figure out where in the text they occur (non docx Word documents are mostly plain text: I sometimes use the `strings` command to read the content).

^L is control-L, character code 12 and sometimes called a "form feed". If you look at a raw Word document in emacs (or any editor that shows control codes), you'll see one of these at the end of each page.